# Defining array size prior to calling a method with referenced array

Tags: c#, arrays, pass-by-reference

I need to consume a method from a COM interface that looks something like this:

```
void method(ref string[] output);
```

Since I don´t know the size of the array prior to the method call, how do I set up my referenced variable:

```
string[] output = new string[???];
```

Is there a smart way to do this or do I need to handle this by providing a "big enough" array & "scale" it down afterwards?

Comment: Isn't there any way you can find out, how much space you need? Usually, functions do have a parameter to either indicate the length of passed data, OR returning the needed length if the provided space is too little.

Comment: Have you considered to use List<string> or ArrayList?

Comment: @ Jamby  : I´m cosuming the interface not writing it, so can´t change that @bash I´m afraid not. It´s not the cleanest API in the world I´m up against and the method returns different size arrays depending on objects I´m using ( this is just one parameter out of many )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when there is no size requested by method signature, it implies that your array will be initialized by method code and you should treat "ref" as "out".

However, this might not be the case. If so, i believe, that solution you suggested is your only choice (if you dont know the expected array size).

Comment: I get the "use of unassigned local variable" error when trying this

Comment: You can easily initialize it with null and see what happens.